# How to get the name of the current tab in AutoIT (SciTE script editor)

Tags: autoit, scite

I want to get the name of the current opened tab.

I tried this:

```
$currentTabName1 = ControlCommand("Publish This! - Bulk Tools", "", "[CLASS:WindowsForms10.BUTTON.app.0.141b42a_r11_ad1;INSTANCE:16]", "CurrentTab", "")
```

But it is just returning me the no. of the tab that is opened.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use GuiTab.au3 UDF.

Here is how I did it.

```
#RequireAdmin
Opt("WinTitleMatchMode", 4) ;1=start, 2=subStr, 3=exact, 4=advanced, -1 to -4=Nocase

#include <GuiTab.au3>

$WindowTitle = "[CLASS:SciTEWindow]"
$Control = "[CLASS:SciTeTabCtrl; INSTANCE:1]"

$currentTabName1 = ControlCommand($WindowTitle, "", $Control, "CurrentTab", "")
$hWnd = ControlGetHandle($WindowTitle, "", $Control)

$array = _GUICtrlTab_GetItem ( $hWnd, $currentTabName1-1 ); -1 because we need 0 based

$CurrentTabText = StringTrimLeft($array[1], 1); trimming &

ConsoleWrite($CurrentTabText & @CRLF)
```

Comment: And how to shift tabs      
I tried this, but it's not working
 
<br/>

`ControlCommand("Content Item Properties", "", "[CLASS:WindowsForms10.SysTabControl32.app.0.141b42a_r11_ad1:INSTANCE:1]", "TabRight", "")`

Comment: You need to edit $WindowTitle and $Control to match your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <GuiTab.au3>

; $control = yoru control instance name
$iIndex = _GUICtrlTab_GetCurSel($control)
$name = _GUICtrlTab_GetItemText($control, $iIndex)
```

[_GUICtrlTab_GetCurSel](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_GUICtrlTab_GetCurSel.htm)

[_GUICtrlTab_GetItemText](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_GUICtrlTab_GetItemText.htm)